# How to use step into and step over in Google Chrome's Web Inspector for debugging Java Script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, breakpoints

I have Chrome, 15.0.874.106 (Developer Build 107270 Linux) Ubuntu 10.04 installed and using it's web inspector to debug my javascript. somewhere, my css images are getting disappeared and i have to figure it out where exactly. So tried to use break points and check. but, once i add the break point, i see that "step into" step over etc are still not enabled. Please help.

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this. This is a full tutorial on how you can run the debugger on Chrome.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging